# Undefined function 'yout' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm building a model (test1) in Matlab for Hydraulic Valve.

When i try the optimization tool i get the following error: Error running optimization. Undefined function 'yout' for input arguments of type 'double'.

This is the code for the objective function i use:

```
function F  = obj_find_valve_param_a_max(x,Q_r)
% Objective function to find the maximum valve area parameter value
% Copyright 2010 MathWorks, Inc.

assignin('base','a_max', x);

% If necessary, reset parameterizaton to second option (table)
model = 'test1';
load_system(model);
blkpth = find_system(bdroot,'ClassName','valve_dir_4_way');
set_param(char(blkpth),'mdl_type','1');
sim(model);

k = [1 1 1 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2];    % Weight multipliers
% Computing objective function
F = 0;
for j = 1:11
    F = F + k(j) * (yout(j) - Q_r(j))^2;
end
end

% EOF


% Script to find directional valve parameter a_max
% Copyright 2010 MathWorks, Inc.

% This script file invokes optimization process to find the orifice
% area at maximum opening for 4-way directional valve when the valve is
% modeled using the first parameterization option (linear relationship
% between control signal and orifice area).

% init_opening - vaalve initial openings [mm]
% A_leak - leakage area  [m^2]
% Q_r - vector of required flow rate at 11 valve displacements
% x0 - initial value for the only variable parameter: orifice maximum area

init_opening = -1;     % mm
A_leak = 1e-9;         % m^2

% Vector of required flow rates. Read out from plot on page 8 in 
% Eaton/Vickers Porportional Directional Valves catalog for KBFDG5V-10 valve
% Actual flow rates are determined at fixed instances of time by exporting
% flow rate measured at the external loop of the valve to the MATLAB
% workspace

Q_r = [0 0 52 150 248 346 450 540 625 670 700];

% Set initial value of the orifice maximum area
x0 = 4.8;           % [cm^2]

% Optimization
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = ...
    fminsearch(@obj_find_valve_param_a_max,x0, ...
    optimset('Tolx',1e-6,'Display','iter'),Q_r);

%bdclose all
```

If i remove from the first code `yout(j) - Q_r(j)` the iteration finishes successfully.
Please does anyone knows how to deal with this error?
Thanks.

Comment: What does yout do? I don't see it defined anywhere here.

Comment: @Compass `yout` is the output of the Simulink model `test1`, but I suspect the OP hasn't configured the model correctly to output the variable to the MATLAB workspace.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that MATLAB does not know what to do with the reference to yout. If yout is a variable (I'm guessing that's your intention) then it must be *initialised* before it can be indexed. The line

> > ```
> > yout(j) - Q_r(j)
> > ```

is an attempt to index the jth element of array yout. Therefor yout must be an array of length at least j. However your code has not initialised the variable, hence the error.

Comment: It's actually incorrect, variables can be indexed without being initialized. If you loop `yout(j)=2`, it will be created in the first iteration. The problem here, as you correctly noted, is that it attempts to access the element of an nonexistent variable.

Comment: `yout` is the output of the Simulink model `test1` that the script runs. I suspect the OP hasn't configured his/her model to output `yout` as a variable, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us your model `test1` and more importantly, how it is configured. You need to have a root-level outport block in your model, and have the model configured to have the output saved to a workspace variable `yout` (see [Data Import/Export Pane](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/gui/data-import-export-pane.html) for details on how to do this). Also, your script (which I suspect is copied from some MathWorks material...) assumes that `yout` is of length 11. Make sure to set the sample time and/or decimation/output options correctly to make sure that's the case.